# Does China have no homeless people?

Tags: china, poverty, homelessness

These two YouTubers (among many other influencers on Twitter and Reddit, etc.) claim that homelessness in China is very rare or almost non-existent after intentional searches. Almost all of their audience believes that there are no homeless people in China.

Both walk the streets in Chinese cities with cameras, looking for homeless people, and finding the streets are clear.

- [Where Are CHINA’s HOMELESS People?! TRUTH!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-hzLOkKRiQ)

  > Despite this global situation happening from America, through Europe to Africa and Asia, countries like China seem to be handling the situation very well with nearly all the streets in China having almost no homeless people.
- [Searching The Streets Of CHINA at 2AM for Homeless People!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHS_-vqnt6A)

  > Homelessness in China has become quiet the talk, especially on the Western Media. I've lived here nearly 5 years and I've never seen a homeless person in China

Does China really have no homeless people?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homelessness_in_China), there were millions of homeless people in the early 2010s, and efforts have done in recent years. I have not seen any evidence there that supports the claim that there are no homeless people in China.

Based on my personal experience, the answer is no, and they are not rare. I saw them in parks of Guangzhou years ago when I was there, and I still often see them hiding in/around railway stations, in 24-hour running restaurants or cybercafés, in cars stopping by streets, under bridges or in other places at night in the city where I live in 2023. And it is hardly common sense that the homeless can be allowed in China to stay in streets (where those influencers have searched) as they are in free countries.

Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: Deleted a lot of people sharing opinions or posting pseudo-answers in the comments. If you have references, use the answer box. If you don't, go get some.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. In title you ask if there are "no homeless people" in China, then in first paragraph you change the claim to "homelessness is rare" and in the last paragraph you say that you see the homeless people under bridges and around railway stations yourself, answering your own question. Is there something more specific you wanted to ask? For example "Why people say there is no homelessness in China"?

Comment: Any claims about "no one" or "everyone" should generally be treated as approximations. No matter how hard a society tries, it's practically impossible for a policy to be complete. So something like "no homeless people" should be interpreted as "a negligible amount of homeless people".

Comment: @ReverentLapwing I saw many influencers saying that there are no homeless people after they had intentionally searched for the homeless, but I personally and unintentionally have found many of them this year. This question is to disprove those influencers' statement that there are no homeless people in China.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing Thanks for your feedback, and I have updated my question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Lzn I see, so you want to know if the homeless people you see are an exception or if the claims of low homelessness are false. Personally, I would write "Where I live, I often see them hiding themselves ..." but I don't know if that's an actual improvement or just pedantism on my part.

Comment: @ReverentLapwing I have improved the question following your advice. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Lzn it was clear before but not it's perfect :)

Comment: The people making the claim are "influencers", people paid to spread a message or promote a brand. If they make a video about nothing else than living conditions in a specific country and shine a good light on it, it's probably because someone paid for that message to be published... it wouldn't be the first time falsehoods are spread by influencers (or China).

Comment: @ReverentLapwing It has been updated again, and please check.

Comment: I feel it's worth noting that A) China deals in propaganda quite a lot and B) I would never trust influencers nor videos with 'TRUTH' in the title.

Comment: The lack of homeless people may very well have something to do with the way in which unemployeed people in china are basically given the choice of re-education or being sold as modern day slaves in China's indentured servitude program.

Comment: In China being unemployed is basically on par with being a criminal.

Answer (score 32):

According to the following photos ([Anti-homeless spikes: ‘Sleeping rough opened my eyes to the city’s barbed cruelty’](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/feb/18/defensive-architecture-keeps-poverty-undeen-and-makes-us-more-hostile)), **there are probably homeless people**: (at least until 2015-2018 -- the article date)

> **[The Guardian:](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/feb/18/defensive-architecture-keeps-poverty-undeen-and-makes-us-more-hostile)**
> Sculptor Fabian Brunsing brought a satirical eye to the issue by creating the “pay bench”, an art installation of a park bench that retracts its metal spikes for a limited time when the prospective sitter feeds it a coin. **Chinese officials, completely missing the joke, thought that this was a great idea and installed similar benches in Yantai Park of the Shangdong province.**

[image]

Also see [Anti-Homeless Poles in Guangxi Render Sidewalk Unusable](https://www.thatsmags.com/china/post/22993/guangxi-authorities-erect-forest-of-poles-to-keep-out-homeless) which includes the image below: (Date: 2015-2018)

> According to Guangxi News, a small community of approximately 10 rough-sleepers had begun to make the covered walkway their home in 2016, sleeping on cardboard pallets and using the area to store collected recyclables for future sale.
>
> The method that the Liuzhou authorities employed is known as ‘hostile architecture’ – a technique long ubiquitous in the UK and parts of North America and now slowly gaining ground in China – wherein everyday objects are deliberately made less comfortable, useful or accessible in order to bring about a desired social effect.
>
> Take this underpass in Guangzhou for instance, where intimidating concrete spikes have been installed to discourage so-called vagrants, or anyone else for that matter, from stopping for a rest.

[image]

Comment: The "anti-homeless poles ... render sidewalk unusable" photo is slightly misleading, for which I blame the article being quoted. It is possible to see that it is not uniformly flat hence is actually an apron in front of the building, and in one of the original photos it is possible to see that the bollards do not continue beyond the far edge of the property. Hence, blaming "the authorities" is unfair in this specific case.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I'm confused by your statement. Are sidewalks always "uniformly flat" where you are?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes. They certainly don't have steep car ramps crossing them like that.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Dang, well that's handy. Probably an American suburb? These things happen to sidewalks in cities all the time, although I would concede that's a pretty steep cutout.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm a European in the UK, and they don't happen in European cities.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd it's unclear what issue you're raising here. Are you saying the bollards serve a purpose other than hostile architecture against rough sleepers (which is their relevance to the question) or that the claim they were installed by public authorities is questionable because it looks like private land?

Comment: @Will I'm saying that they look like they were installed privately to keep people off the building's apron. I'd emphasise that I'm neutral on the question and answers.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I see, but I don't see how that makes the photo misleading, as you put it.  It quite straightforwardly demonstrates the presence of rough sleepers seeking shelter. It's unfortunate that it's sourced from an article that describes the site as a sidewalk in its title, which as you say might not be accurate, but at worst that's a minor point of distraction

Comment: the photos could just as well be anti e-bike

Comment: There are plenty of jurisdictions and laws where sidewalks are mandated but happen to be on private land. The picture above quite clearly shows a sidewalk - there isn't another one between it and the parking spaces and the street. For the public it makes no difference who owns that land on paper (nor does it, to a large degree, who is accountable for the architectural hostility).

Answer (score 28):

There are homeless people in China.

For example, [this video creator](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1cm4y1t7mW/?spm_id_from=333.999.0.0&vd_source=32f944a9651d2cd6e7e103a187bb84f8) is a homeless man in the suburbs of Hangzhou and living in an abandoned villa. After neighbors called the police, he provided his ID card and confirmed that he was not a fugitive. The police reminded him not to light a fire at home and to be careful of fires.

- Using Google's "transate to English" option translates the comments and the title and provides some English subtitles. These all serve to confirm that the video's subject is as claimed.
  The heading is "You always like to see me sleeping in the stairwell, but now I am kicked out of the big villa by the police, so I can only sleep in the stairwell."

The [Sanhe Masters](https://www.sixthtone.com/news/1006145) operate in places with concentrated manufacturing industries such as Guangzhou because there are many job opportunities there. They adhere to the principle of "one day of work, three days of play".

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/) We require answers to include references to support your claims. The parts of this question which are about what *you* saw (in China and Europe should be removed. The parts of this question which are about what *you* think the causes are should be removed. Unfortunately the two videos are not in English, so it is hard for many of us to judge whether they are relevant or accurate.

Comment: @Oddthinking It seems to me that requiring a particular language for a source would just introduce unnecessary bias. Evidence is evidence regardless of the language or how easily someone can judge it, and ruling out an entire category of evidence doesn't seem an effective way to arrive at the truth.

Comment: An answer written in Mandarin might also be perfectly correct, but that doesn't mean we must accept it here either. If we can't check the evidence for credibility and accuracy and relevance, it's simply not evidence at all.

Comment: @Nij The 15 people who upvoted seem to disagree with you.

Comment: For someone on a Skeptics site, it's very interesting to place huge importance on the popularity of an offhand comment that says claims on the internet can be taken at face value as long as there's a YouTube video. @A.R.

Comment: @JBentley: Please read what I wrote again. Sources do not need to be in English. However, typically we recommend that a snippet of a source (e.g. a transcription of a video) be included in the answer so we can see it matches the claim the OP is making. If that is not English, we suggest it be translated (by the OP or a later editor) so it can be judged by a majority of the audience. Finding obscure evidence and making it available to our readers is a key job of someone writing an answer here.

Comment: @A.R.: This question made it to the Hot Network Questions list. (Welcome to all the new Skeptics readers!) As a result, the voting can be quite skewed - I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: @Nij You are conflating the *nature* of the source (e.g. YouTube video) (for which your point is valid) with the *language* of the source. Nobody claimed in a comment that "claims on the internet can be taken at face value as long as there's a YouTube video" - that's a mischaracterisation of the comment. The issue was whether the language being non-English should detract from the claim. That issue applies equally to a YouTube video as it does to a peer reviewed journal paper.

Comment: I am conflating nothing. The videos are literally useless here, they may as well not exist. The only support they add to the post is their existence, they have no effect and may as well not exist.

Comment: @Nij No; even an unreliable external source (if cited properly) usually provides a huge pile of claimed facts and interconnections.  Such details increase naive credibility, and practically simplify disproving reliability of the source - a source that says "there is a purple rock on the far side of the moon" is impossible to refute: one that gives an entire description of how that rock got there (launch schedules, budgets, who put it there) is insanely easier to prove unreliable (so long as the detail is held equally true as the claim).  So yes, a rich external source is more evidence.

Comment: Using Google's "transate to English" option translates the comments and the title and provides some English subtitles. These all serve to confirm that the video's subject is as claimed.
The heading is "You always like to see me sleeping in the stairwell, but now I am kicked out of the big villa by the police, so I can only sleep in the stairwell."

Comment: I saw that my answer was modified and most of it was deleted, and I also saw the reason for the modification.
 
Sorry, I didn't read the Code of Conduct well before answering. I thought it was a chat forum similar to reddit.

I hope to provide you with a higher quality reply next time, and provide quotes and links for reference.

If the external link is in a language other than English, you can use Google Translate, as the Chinese government or NGOs rarely publish information in English on the Internet.

Comment: @HpDD Welcome on Skeptics.SE. After the edit, there is no doubt that your answer is useful, so there is no need to be sorry. Looking forward to your next contributions !

Answer (score 19):

I searched out the [Ministry of Civil Affairs](https://www.mca.gov.cn/) documents 《2022 年民政事业发展统计公报》 (and similarly for other years) wherein we have statistics for the *number of homeless shelters and how much they're utilized* in China (links to the pdfs are given after the Chinese quote):

> 截至 2018 年底，全国共有其他提供住宿的民政服务机构 1824 个，床位 12.7 万张。其中各类救助管理机构 1534 个，床位 10.2 万张，全年救助生活无着流浪乞讨人员 155.0 万人次（在站救助 119.8 万人次，站外救助 35.2 万人次）。  ([pdf](https://www.mca.gov.cn/images3/www2017/file/201908/1565920301578.pdf))
> [Google Translate:]  **As of the end of 2018**, there were 1,824 other civil service agencies providing accommodation across the country, with 127,000 beds. Among them, there are **1,534 various rescue and management institutions** with 102,000 beds, and **1.550 million homeless and beggars were rescued** throughout the year (1.198 million people were rescued on site and 352,000 people were rescued outside the site).
>
> 至 2019 年底，全国共有其他提供住宿的民政服务机构 1828 个，床位 12.2 万张。其中流浪乞讨人员救助管理站 1545 个，床位 9.6 万张，全年救助流浪乞讨人员 131.5 万人次（在站救助 98.3 万人次，站外救助 33.2 万人次）。 ([pdf](https://www.mca.gov.cn/images3/www2017/file/202009/1601261242921.pdf))
> [Google Translate:] **By the end of 2019**, there were 1,828 other civil service agencies providing accommodation across the country, with 122,000 beds. Among them, there are **1,545 homeless and beggars rescue and management stations** with 96,000 beds, and **1.315 million homeless and beggars were rescued** throughout the year (983,000 people were rescued at the station and 332,000 people were assisted outside the station).
>
> 截至 2020 年底，全国共有其他提供住宿的民政服务机构 1793 个，床位 10.4 万张。其中流浪乞讨人员救助管理机构 1555 个，床位 8.4 万张，全年救助流浪乞讨人员 83.2 万人次。 ([pdf](https://www.mca.gov.cn/images3/www2017/file/202109/1631265147970.pdf))
> [Google Translate]: **As of the end of 2020**, there were 1,793 other civil service agencies providing accommodation across the country, with 104,000 beds. Among them, there are **1,555 homeless and beggars relief and management institutions** with 84,000 beds, and **832,000 homeless and beggars were rescued** throughout the year.
>
> 截至 2021 年底，全国共有其他提供住宿的民政服务机构 1780 个，床位 10.0 万张。其中流浪乞讨人员救助管理机构 1562 个，床位 8.5 万张，全年救助流浪乞讨人员 73.9 万人次。 ([pdf](https://www.mca.gov.cn/images3/www2017/file/202208/2021mzsyfztjgb.pdf))
> [Google Translate:] **As of the end of 2021**, there were 1,780 other civil service agencies providing accommodation across the country, with 100,000 beds. Among them, there are **1,562 homeless and beggars relief and management institutions** with 85,000 beds, and **739,000 homeless and beggars** were rescued throughout the year.
>
> 截至 2022 年底，全国共有其他提供住宿的民政服务机构 1756 个，床位 9.5 万张。其中流浪乞讨人员救助管理机构 1573 个，床位 8.1 万张，全年救助流浪乞讨人员 75.1 万人次。 ([pdf](https://www.mca.gov.cn/n156/n2679/c1662004999979995221/attr/306352.pdf))
> [Google translate:] **As of the end of 2022**, there were 1,756 other civil service agencies providing accommodation across the country, with 95,000 beds. Among them, there are **1,573 homeless and beggars relief and management institutions** with 81,000 beds, and **751,000 homeless and beggars** were rescued throughout the year.

I note here how the Chinese 人次 is a unit meaning "visits" which counts duplicates (like how "views" of a website counts duplicates).  So Google Translate does not precisely translate e.g. 75.1 万人次; it should be "751,000 visits" rather than "751,000 people".

These are up to date, official Chinese Government statistics; I didn't find the 2023 data [here](https://www.mca.gov.cn/n156/n2679/index.html), and it'll likely be published in 2024.  We can conclude that the number of people using homeless shelters in China is somewhere in the ballpark of 100,000 to 1,000,000.  I.e., it's nowhere near 0.

Answer (score 4):

The social credit system in China, which gives 1,000 points to all citizens and then adds or deducts dependent on conduct, is reputedly causing homelessness on a huge scale. This situation has been developing since 2018.

> Dropping to the lowest possible score of 600 can ban you from using public services, buying plane tickets, deny you a loan or even result in a public shaming campaign with your face and ID number displayed in public places.

[China's Social Credit System](https://rtd.rt.com/stories/whos-naughty-or-nice-chinas-social-credit-system/)

However, it is hard to find out the real homeless statistics within China. Much of it is anecdotal.

> Tens of thousands Chinese people with low social credit scores are becoming homeless now.
>
> With a low social credit score in China,  you cannot find a decent job, book a hotel room, travel by train or plane... You are excluded from society!!

[Songpinganq on Twitter - April 16 2023](https://twitter.com/songpinganq/status/1709653628611645901)

Comment: "With a low social credit score (...) You are excluded from society!!" - If the social credit system punishes for antisocial behavior (at least in principle), such as littering, it serves its purpose. Offenders themselves are to be blamed, not the system.